# IIS to grab the latest WCF solution from TFS

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, tfs

It is my first time trying to host my WCF service on IIS having said that I am using TFS to submit the latest code changes, I was wondering how can I make the IIS to point to the latest solution on TFS ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the release management cycle.

You can use something like `Release Management for TFS` to deploy a `WebDeploy` package. This may be overkill if this is not part of a larger deployment effort.

As a quick solution, you may want to look into `TFS Build`. The idea is to create a build definition triggered on each checkin. Create a publish profile in your WCF project and make it deploy the project to the target server using WebDeploy.
On the build definition, set the MSBuild arguments to `/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Build`. Just replace `Build` with the name of the publish profile you just created.

Each checkin will trigger the build, which will deploy the package on the target server using the publish profile.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Johann Blais, The project that I am currently working on is not enterprise level so I guess the second approach is more feasible to do, but then I have to make sure every check in is fully tested and functional :) +1